# int value of COM11?

Tags: c++, rfid

I have a RFID Reader that connect to my computer via COM.

```
1> When the reader connect to my computer via COM3
   C++: OpenComm(3) --> OK

2> When the reader connect to my computer via COM9
   C++: OpenComm(9) --> OK

3> When the reader connect to my computer via COM11
   C++: OpenComm(11) --> Not work
```

I don't know why it not work.

OpenComm(int com) is a attached library for my RFID Reader. So, I need int value of COM11.

Comment: You need to provide much more detail; specifically, you need to show some actual C++ code.

Comment: What reader type of what company?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're using Windows - from the [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation:

> To specify a COM port number greater than 9, use the following syntax:
>   "\.\COM10". This syntax works for all port numbers and hardware that
>   allows COM port numbers to be specified

Comment: OpenComm(int com) is a attached library for my RFID Reader. So, I need int value of COM11.

Comment: Presumably your library doesn't use the required syntax, so no magical int value is going to fix it.